# SciLua: unexpected symbol near ']'

Tags: matrix, lua

Running the following example from the [SciLua](http://scilua.org/index.html) page (my test file is named `test.lua`):

```
-- No global key is set:
local alg  = require "sci.alg"  -- Load sci.alg module.
local dist = require "sci.dist" -- Load sci.dist module.


local function randmatstat(t)
  local n = 5
  local v, w = alg.vec(t), alg.vec(t)
  for i=1,t do
      local a, b, c, d = randn(n, n), randn(n, n), randn(n, n), randn(n, n)
      local P = alg.join(a..b..c..d)
      local Q = alg.join(a..b, c..d)
      v[i] = alg.trace((P[]`**P[])^^4) -- Matrix transpose, product and power.
      w[i] = alg.trace((Q[]`**Q[])^^4) -- Matrix transpose, product and power.
  end
  return sqrt(stat.var(v))/stat.mean(v), sqrt(stat.var(w))/stat.mean(w)
end
```

I keep getting the error:

> test.lua:13: unexpected symbol near ']'

Most other modules work fine, but the problem occurs only when using matrices. I appreciate your help.

**Update:**

With the helpful answer by @stepelu, I'm very thankful to him, the following complete example now works fine:

```
local alg     = require 'sci.alg'
local prng    = require 'sci.prng'
local stat    = require 'sci.stat'
local dist    = require 'sci.dist'

local min, sqrt, random, abs = math.min, math.sqrt, math.random, math.abs
local rng = prng.std()
local vec, mat, join = alg.vec, alg.mat, alg.join

local function randn(r, c)
    local x = mat(r, c)
    for i=1,#x do 
        x[i] = dist.normal(0, 1):sample(rng) 
    end
    return x
end

local function randmatstat(t)
  local n = 5
  local v, w = alg.vec(t), alg.vec(t)
  for i=1,t do
      local a, b, c, d = randn(n, n), randn(n, n), randn(n, n), randn(n, n)
      local P = alg.join(a..b..c..d)
      local Q = alg.join(a..b, c..d)
      v[i] = alg.trace((P[]`**P[])^^4) -- Matrix transpose, product and power.
      w[i] = alg.trace((Q[]`**Q[])^^4) -- Matrix transpose, product and power.
  end
  return sqrt(stat.var(v))/stat.mean(v), sqrt(stat.var(w))/stat.mean(w)
end

print(randmatstat(1000))
```

with the expected output:

```
0.75865001347735    0.74932678346271
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

Comment: smells it does not like the backtick

Comment: I see the downvote, but this is my day 1 learning Lua, may be I'm doing something stupid. Could the downvoter please give me a hint instead and be more positive?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski -- The backticks are for matrix transpose as the page says.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski -- And my question is why doesn't it like the backtick? Why doesn't it recognize `**` or `^^`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Author of SciLua here.

In order to enable the SciLua language extensions it's necessary to install the `sci-lang` package additionally to the `sci` one.

If you installed SciLua as part of the ULua distribution as shown on scilua.org (preferred approach) then it suffices to execute the script via the `scilua` executable instead of the `lua` one.

Otherwise, if you opted for a manual installation of the `sci` and `sci-lag` on the top of an existing LuaJIT installation, the following applies.
The package contains a __bin folder, and when installed via upkg (in ULua) then executable-scripts for each OS are automatically created from the lua file contained in this folder.
So if you opt for manual install it's necessary for you to create an executable script yourself (i.e. on Linux a file named `scilua` with exec permissions, with the content of `__bin/scilua.lua` + bash shebang).

Comment: Thank you so much, I was mislead by the [ulua page](http://ulua.io/) command `# On Windows:
cd folder_containing_ulua/ulua
lua      [options] [script [args]]`. Now every thing works fine. I'm grateful to you, I was going to give up the whole idea of Scilua which I liked so much.